# Using Python to save a file that is sent to browser when visiting URL

Tags: python-3.x, csv, file, download

When I visit the URL below in a browser, it automatically downloads a CSV. As the contents are updated daily, I want to write a Python command to get the latest file each time.

I've tried wget, requests and urllib.request - all without luck.

```
url = 'https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/api/v1/data?filters=areaType=overview&structure=%7B%22areaType%22:%22areaType%22,%22areaName%22:%22areaName%22,%22areaCode%22:%22areaCode%22,%22date%22:%22date%22,%22newPeopleVaccinatedFirstDoseByPublishDate%22:%22newPeopleVaccinatedFirstDoseByPublishDate%22,%22cumPeopleVaccinatedFirstDoseByPublishDate%22:%22cumPeopleVaccinatedFirstDoseByPublishDate%22%7D&format=csv'
```

Anyone got any ideas? TIA

Comment: What exactly did you try and what were the results? I retrieved the file with `requests` just fine...

Comment: I'm using that file to 1) establish the capacity of UK vaccination sites (i.e. people to administer and premises to host vaccination centers) and 2) then doing a time series to work out when it's likely that UK population will be "fully vaccinated". Thanks for the solution, this means I can re-process my data daily, as that file it is updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works just fine for me:

```
import requests

url = 'https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/api/v1/data?filters=areaType=overview&structure=%7B%22areaType%22:%22areaType%22,%22areaName%22:%22areaName%22,%22areaCode%22:%22areaCode%22,%22date%22:%22date%22,%22newPeopleVaccinatedFirstDoseByPublishDate%22:%22newPeopleVaccinatedFirstDoseByPublishDate%22,%22cumPeopleVaccinatedFirstDoseByPublishDate%22:%22cumPeopleVaccinatedFirstDoseByPublishDate%22%7D&format=csv'

r = requests.get(url)

with open("uk_data.csv", "wb") as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

The content is a bytes object, so you need to open the file in binary mode.